# Compile error after installing AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, afnetworking-2

I just installled AFNetwokring 2.0 and first compiled it with a simulator, that working 100% and no errors were found. The test call i made also worked as it should. Then i tried compiling it for a real iPhone device, and now i receive this error, when trying to build:

```
Ld /Users/sorendidriksen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GB_Mobil_DK-abwnrramdycsilhhfusihgjqvead/Build/Intermediates/GB\ Mobil\ DK.build/Debug-iphoneos/GB\ Mobil\ DK.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GB\ Mobil\ DK normal armv7
    cd /Volumes/TCOSX25GB/CloudStation/GolfBox/GolfBox_Code/iOS_build_DK/GB_Build_1.7.2.0
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk -L/Users/sorendidriksen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GB_Mobil_DK-abwnrramdycsilhhfusihgjqvead/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/sorendidriksen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GB_Mobil_DK-abwnrramdycsilhhfusihgjqvead/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/sorendidriksen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GB_Mobil_DK-abwnrramdycsilhhfusihgjqvead/Build/Intermediates/GB\ Mobil\ DK.build/Debug-iphoneos/GB\ Mobil\ DK.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GB\ Mobil\ DK.LinkFileList -dead_strip -lxml2 -all_load -ObjC -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -framework QuartzCore -framework MapKit -lz.1.2.5 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework CFNetwork -framework SystemConfiguration -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CoreLocation -framework AddressBook -framework CoreData -lPods -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/sorendidriksen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GB_Mobil_DK-abwnrramdycsilhhfusihgjqvead/Build/Intermediates/GB\ Mobil\ DK.build/Debug-iphoneos/GB\ Mobil\ DK.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GB\ Mobil\ DK_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/sorendidriksen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GB_Mobil_DK-abwnrramdycsilhhfusihgjqvead/Build/Intermediates/GB\ Mobil\ DK.build/Debug-iphoneos/GB\ Mobil\ DK.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GB\ Mobil\ DK

ld: library not found for -lPods
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have no idea on how to fix this, anyone out there able to help plz?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Possible Issue

Your device has another architecture which doesn't not support all architectures provided by pods.

## Solution

Go to project, `Build Phases` -> `Architectures` -> `Build active architecture only` and set it `NO`. Run the project again.

Hope it helps

Comment: I know I'm opening the correct file (GB Mobil DK.xcworkspace). And the pods should be installed correctly right? since it runs as it should as long as i use a simulator?

Comment: On my way to find this it poped up asking my if i wanted to auto convert something with the architecture i pressed yes and now it works. Thx for leading me to the right answer:)

Comment: @user2408952 Do you not think that this answer deserves an upvote if you found it useful?  I cannot see how you can accept it and still not find it useful.

Comment: Ofc it does, there ya go