# CocoaPods not linking with the project

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I have a project that uses CocoaPods. It was working but something got broken.

It does compile if I target the simulator, but If I target the devise (Build or Archive) it throws a linker error.

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myuser/ios/share/share/libPods.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/myuser/ios/share/share/libPods.a
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestOperationManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in BackendProxy.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I really need some help because I am really stucked.

Thanks!

EDIT: i deleted that libPods.a, that was an old one, and now it's giving me:

```
ld: library not found for -lPods
```

But only on Archive or Build for iosDevice, this is still working on the simulator.

Comment: Try my asnwer here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23405076/compile-error-after-installing-afnetworking-2-0/23405139#23405139

Comment: I tried it, it didnt work

Comment: Hm, try installing the pods again, and open workspace, clean and run.

Comment: tried it too, no luck

Comment: hmm, go to build phases -> Compile Sources and check out if there is any BackendProxy.m, if there is also BackendProxy.h try to remove it, and leave only BackendProxy.m. If there is not add BackendProxy.m.

Comment: BackendProxy is my proxy to make calls to the backend, in which i use AFHTTPRequestOperationManager, from AFNetworking pod

Answer (score 3):

Try removing `armv7s` from `valid architectures` section.

```
Build Settings -> Architectures -> Valid Architectures
```

[image: Xcode Build Settings]

Comment: didn't work! i edited the post with a change i just did.

Comment: This is weird, right now I can't test it, because I am not at work, Ill give it a try tomorrow